# Get a list of mutex?

Tags: mutex

A program creates a mutex as part of its start-up.  I don't know the format of this mutex so I wondered if there is a way to get a list of all non-abandoned mutex, open the program, get a new list and see if I can find the mutex by removing all duplicate entries.

Is there a way to get this list?

Answer (score 19):

If you're on Windows, [WinObj](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657.aspx) can show you named mutexes. Or you can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find out which objects a specific process has open.

Comment: And what about unnamed mutexes?

Comment: If a mutex doesn't have a name, you can't get at it (easily) from another process, so it's a moot point.

Answer (score 8):

If you have WinObj.exe it is likely that you also have handle.exe
which is also from the SysInternals-Suite.

Occasionally I found

```
handle -a |findstr /C:Mutant /C:pid:
```

to be helpful.
This also displays unnamed Mutexes.

BTW: 
If you dont want to rely on the output format compatibility (I used version v3.51) you should capture the whole output of handle -a and search manually or use

```
handle -a -p %YOUR_PID%
```

Comment: The **Handle** can be downloaded from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle

Answer (score 4):

- Download WinObj from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/winobj
- Unzip and run
- Click menu `File | Run as administrator`
- Click `sessions` in left hand navigation pane
- Click on sub nodes until one displays `BaseNamedObjects`
- Click on 'BaseNamedObjects'

The named mutexes ( "Mutant" ) will display in the right hand pane.  There will be a lot of them!