# How can I programatically list all global mutants in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, mutex, handle

How can I get a list of all global named mutexes/mutants in use on a Windows system?

I know [WinObj can do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389868/get-a-list-of-mutex), but how can I do that myself using the win32api?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @HansPassant That does not apply. My problem is that I need a list of all mutexes on the system, but I don't know how to get it. If you'd like to know why, it's to look for mutexes created by malware processes.

Comment: And how are you going to know whether a given process is malware or not? If a mutex is not named then it is internal to its parent process, and if a mutex is named then you can simply open the mutex by its name directly to test if it exists or not. What are you really trying to solve?

Comment: I'm sure Sean knows how to open a named mutex. He's looking for a way to list the `Mutant` objects in `\BaseNamedObjects`. This requires the [`NtQueryDirectoryObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470238) system call, but Microsoft doesn't support making system calls directly from user mode. Here's a command line that will do this for you: `accesschk -accepteula -qost Mutant \BaseNamedObjects`. Unfortunately Sysinternals utilities aren't [licensed](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb847944) for redistribution.

Comment: @RemyLebeau [By checking against known "bad" named mutexes](http://digital-forensics.sans.org/blog/2012/07/24/mutex-for-malware-discovery-and-iocs). Malware often uses named mutexes to prevent multiple instamces. I don't want to test opening the mutexes, and risk triggering AV alerts on my own scanner.

Comment: @eryksun Thank you. I'm assuming NtQueryDirectoryObject is what sysinternals uses? I don't recall it using a driver or even admin rights to do it...

Comment: Yes, it doesn't use a driver. You can run accesschk.exe under a debugger (e.g. 32-bit cdb.exe) with breakpoints set on `ntdll!NtOpenDirectoryObject` and `ntdll!NtQueryDirectoryObject` to inspect the calls it makes.